# customizing functionality of field lookups for custom Django model fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a custom model field `YearWithSurenessField` which is represented in python by the custom datatype `YearWithSureness`. The constructor for `YearWithSureness` is `YearWithSureness(year='', is_certain=False)`, where `year` is either `''` or a four-digit year (as a string), and `is_certain` is a bool representing whether or not I'm certain that the given year is correct. Model fields of this type are stored in my database in the form *year/is_certain*, e.g. "2008/True", "2011/False", "/False", etc.

As an example, in the `Member` model, I have a field `grad_year = YearWithSurenessField(...)` which stores a member's graduation year along with whether or not I know for certain that the year I stored is correct.

What I'd like to be able to do is use something like

```
Member.objects.filter(grad_year__year=2011)
```

to get a `QuerySet` of all the Members whose grad_year is either "2011/True" or "2011/False". Similarly, I'd like to be able to use something like

```
Member.objects.filter(grad_year__range=(2000, 2011))
```

to get a `QuerySet` of all the Members whose grad_year is in the range 2000 thru 2011 irrespective of whether `grad_year.is_certain` is True or False.

Is this possible? I know that I could use Member.objects.filter(grad_year__contains="2011") to get the first result, but I'd like to be able to use __year.

Here're the relevant classes, trimmed of extraneous code:

```
class YearWithSureness(object):
    def __init__(self, year='', is_certain=False):
        # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return "{year}/{is_certain}".format(year=self.year,
                                            is_certain=self.is_certain)

class YearWithSurenessField(models.Field):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...

    def to_python(self, value):
        # ...

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        # ...

    def get_prep_lookup(self, lookup_type, value):
        if lookup_type in ('month', 'day'):
            raise TypeError('Lookup type {0} not supported.'.format(lookup_type))
        else:
            return super(YearWithSurenessField, self).get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        # ...
```

Comment: You should just use a custom manager that accepts the ranges parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I can't understand why you need to have such a custom field.  As far as I can see, 'year' and 'is_certain' are perfectly suitable to store in 2 separated fields.  By doing so, first,  searching by year or year range is easier.  Second, searching will be also be significantly more efficient, especially when there are a large amount of data.  Last but not least, you don't need to bother how to correctly implement a customized field anymore.

So I suggest you explain the fundamental reason why you need to store those two naturally disparate types of data into a single column in your database table.  And maybe we can point out a simpler way to achieve your real goals.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something that I found useful:
[Creating custom Field Lookups in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203179/creating-custom-field-lookups-in-django)

A more flexible way to do this is to write a custom QuerySet as well as a custom manager. Working from ozan's code:

```
class PersonQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def in_age_range(self, min, max):
        return self.filter(age__gte=min, age__lt=max)

class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
         return PersonQuerySet(self.model)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.get_query_set(), name)

class Person(models.Model):
    age = #...
    objects = PersonManager()
```

This allows you to chain your custom query. So both these queries would be valid:

```
Person.objects.in_age_range(20,30)
Person.objects.exclude(somefield = some_value).in_age_range(20, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the behavior of get_prep_lookup to return just the year value when lookup_type == 'year'? You could return int(value.split('/')[0])

I'm not sure implementing such a custom field is the best option, is there a really good reason to avoid splitting the values into two separated fields?