# how to put % in string

Tags: mysql

I have tried using `'%%'` and `'%'` already, none of these working in the below scenario.

The output of query is:

```
UPPER('field') LIKE UPPER('string')
```

But I want the output as:

```
UPPER('field') LIKE UPPER('%string%')
```

Comment: DId you try escaping them with backslashes?

Comment: return 'UPPER({0}) LIKE UPPER(%{1}%)'.format(lhs,rhs)

Comment: BTW you know that '%something%' type queries will not use indexes on sqlite and mysql and UPPER will make it impossible to use the index on postgresql also (unless of course you define a functional index)

Comment: @elethan Yes, tried backslash, it doesn't work, gives error on compilation

Comment: as a user with more than 500 reps, you should know better than to make statements like 'giving me error'.

Comment: `'UPPER({0}) LIKE UPPER(%{1}%)'.format(lhs,rhs)` most definitely does not cause that eror. Type it into the python console and confirm for yourself.

Comment: What is the output of trying: `return 'UPPER(%s) LIKE UPPER(%%%s%%)' % (lhs, rhs), params`

Comment: @user1735921 what is the actual value of lhs and rhs in your example?

Comment: @user1735921: that means you typed a % too many, you must have had %%%%s%% instead of %%%s%%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to combine a Lookup and a [Transform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-lookups/#a-bilateral-transformer-example) in the same query. You can only do one at a time. This is because [Lookup automatically adds parentheses around `lhs_params` and `rhs_params`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/lookups.py#L87).

When you tried `return 'UPPER(%s) LIKE UPPER(%%%s%%)' % (lhs, rhs), params` this is what caused the unsupported character error.

You need to construct your [Bilateral Transformer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-lookups/#a-bilateral-transformer-example) to convert both sides to uppercase separately from your lookup function.

Really what you want is to use the `Transform` from the docs combined with `__contains` which replaces your `LIKE` Lookup:

```
from django.db.models import Transform

class UpperCase(Transform):
    lookup_name = 'upper'
    function = 'UPPER'
    bilateral = True
```

Your query would be:

```
YourObject.objects.filter(yourvalue__upper__contains="something")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `process_rhs` method and modify the value there:

```
class MyCustomLookup(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'custom_lookuptest'
    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return 'UPPER(%s) LIKE UPPER(%s)' % (lhs, rhs), params
    def process_rhs(self, compiler, connection):
        value = '%%%s%%' % self.rhs
        if self.bilateral_transforms:
            if self.rhs_is_direct_value():
                value = Value(value, output_field=self.lhs.output_field)
            value = self.apply_bilateral_transforms(value)
            value = value.resolve_expression(compiler.query)
        if hasattr(value, 'get_compiler'):
            value = value.get_compiler(connection=connection)
        if hasattr(value, 'as_sql'):
            sql, params = compiler.compile(value)
            return '(' + sql + ')', params
        if hasattr(value, '_as_sql'):
            sql, params = value._as_sql(connection=connection)
            return '(' + sql + ')', params
        else:
            return self.get_db_prep_lookup(value, connection)
```